# matlab - calculate the 95 % interval around the mean

Tags: matlab, statistics, confidence-interval

If I have a vector of monthly-averaged values like

```
aa = [1,2,3,2,1,3,5,3,4,8,9,7;...
    11,12,3,21,1,3,15,3,4,8,19,7;...
    21,2,3,2,1,23,5,3,34,84,9,7]';
```

where each column refers to the monthly-averaged values from different locations and each row represents the month of year. I can calculate the average of all of the sites as:

```
mean_a = nanmean(aa,2);
```

and thus can plot the averages of these as:

```
plot(1:12, mean_a);
```

How would I now calculate the 95 % confidence interval around these mean values?

Any advice would be appreciated.

My attempt:

Assuming a normal distribution:

```
aa = [1,2,3,2,1,3,5,3,4,8,9,7;...
    11,12,3,21,1,3,15,3,4,8,19,7;...
    21,2,3,2,1,23,5,3,34,84,9,7]';

mean_a = nanmean(aa,2);
sem = (nanstd(aa')./sqrt(size(aa,2))).*1.96;
errorbar(1:12,mean_a,sem);
```

Comment: If you have reason to believe that your data is normally distributed then http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Confidence-Interval

Comment: Your question is too broad. _How_ do you want to calculate that interval? You can do it assuming a certain distribution, or directly using your data (bootstrap-like) to estimate the required percentiles

Comment: Assuming that the data is normally distributed, how do you calculate the 95 % confidence interval around the mean?

Comment: Ideally you would need to know the mean and standard deviation of that distribution, and then apply `normcdf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the quantile using `quantile`: or if you know the distribution, multiply the standard deviation with the correct quantile value.

Comment: Well the 95 percentile confidence interval around them mean is approximately `mean +- std*1.96`. so it seems so.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for the record, [here is a function called confidence_intervals()](https://github.com/JacobD10/SoundZone_Tools/blob/master/confidence_intervals.m) that will give any confidence intervals for a dataset and can be used with the [errorbar() function](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html) in Matlab. It can also be used, given the optional argument, to find the confidence intervals with the [log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) variance.

As in your example, the code becomes:

```
aa = [1,2,3,2,1,3,5,3,4,8,9,7;...
      11,12,3,21,1,3,15,3,4,8,19,7;...
      21,2,3,2,1,23,5,3,34,84,9,7]';

errorbar( 1:12, mean(aa), confidence_intervals( aa, 95 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!